# Linq Group By On Two Properties That maybe different or the same

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to do a group by on two properties who at 95% of the time will be the same, but sometimes it may not by

```
class Game
{
   string AwayTeamPoolId;  // 122
   string HomeTeamPoolId;  // 144
}
```

I would like to group all games from the same pool from a list of games.  As I mentioned above most of the time this value will be the same for both away/home teams.  However there might be a cross pool play game where the values are different.  With Linq how can I group say the game by having the awayteampoolid with the group 122, and have hometeampoolid grouped with 144?  It's easy if they are the same but different Im not sure.

```
122
  Game 1 (122/122)
  Game 2 (122/144)

144
  Game 2 (122/144)
  Game 3 (144/144)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data along with a sample result?

Comment: Is the information at the end not helpful?

Comment: Are you saying you want a single item to [possibly] appear in 2 places, ie once for [and 'under'] each _distinct_ PoolId?

Comment: Yes basically, only way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Concat` (union all) the list of `AwayTeamPool` and `HomeTeamPool` and then group on that like this:

```
var query = games.Select(x => new { Game=x, PoolId = x.AwayTeamPoolId })
                 .Concat(games.Where(x => x.HomeTeamPoolId != x.AwayTeamPoolId)
                              .Select(x=> new { Game=x, PoolId = x.HomeTeamPoolId })
                 .GroupBy(x => x.PoolId, x => x.Game);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) combined with [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397696.aspx).

```
var groupedGames = games.GroupBy(
           game => new { game.AwayTeamPoolId, game.HomeTeamPoolId });
```

To get the games where `AwayTeamPoolId` is 122 and `HomeTeamPoolId` is 144:

```
var games = groupedGames.Single(
                group => group.Key.AwayTeamPoolId = 122 && group.Key.HomeTeamPoolId = 144)
```

Comment: But wouldnt that create a group that contains 122 and 144?  I want all games with 122 together (even if the home team has 144) and vice versa.

Comment: @MikeFlynn It'll create a group for each possible combination of `AwayTeamPoolId`+`HomeTeamPoolId`. If for some reason this is not what you want, please provide sample input and expected output so we can help you out.

Comment: Didnt I do that above?

Comment: @MikeFlynn I think I understand now, and I think Aducci nailed it.